# CKFinder2 - 404 File Not Found

Tags: apache-http-server, tomcat

We use CKFinder2 since long time, and now we moved to a new hardware, with same domain. Unfortunately, something is missing in some configuration file, and trying to open the "Search on the server" dialog we receive a 404 File Not Found error ( see https://www.sbt.ti.ch/tmp/CKFinder404.png ) and we can't figure out how to solve the problem.
I searched for a long time on the Internet, without result, and we can't afford to buy a new version. Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!
Kind regards
Stefano

Comment: You'll need to give us a lot more information in order for us to begin to understand your issue and hopefully get you an answer. You are the only set of eyes and ears we have on this problem. You'd have to start with the server configuration, the application configuration, and probably a lot of other things.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you're right, but I solved my question, after moving to a new server I had to do a small change in a path in WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>ConnectorServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>
    /sbtadm/ckfinder/core/connector/java/connector.java
  </url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
```